# Doxygen warnings in Eigen 3.2.10

Tags: doxygen

Not sure what forum is best for this.

I created a (default) C++-11 tool project in Xcode 8.0 and referenced Eigen/Core using Eigen 3.2.10.  I got 47 warnings before writing any code, all related to Doxygen comments, e.g.,

Empty paragraph passed to '\sa' command (in Comments.h, line 52)

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answered:

Turns out there is a global flag for documentation warnings that can be turned off.